# Prove that $QBYZ$ is cyclic

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Circles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$intersect each other at points $A$ and $B$. Point $C$ lies on
the tangent line from $A$ to $\omega_1$ such that $\angle ABC = 90^{°}$. Arbitrary line
passes through $C$ and cuts $\omega_2$ at points $P$ and $Q$. Lines $AP$ and $AQ$ cut
$\omega_1$ for the second time at points $X$ and $Z$ respectively. Let $Y$ be the foot
of altitude from $A$ to $PQ$.

Prove that $QBYZ$ is cyclic.

I proved that $AYBC$ and $PYBX$ are cyclic but I have no idea how to prove that $QBYZ$ is cyclic.[image]

Comment: In your diagram $Y$ doesn't look like foot of altitude on $XZ$. Can you check again where $Y$ is located?

Comment: In the statement it says that $Y$ is the foot of the altitude from $A$ to $XZ$ but in the figure, it is the foot of the altitude from $A$ to $PC$.I belive that the second one,to $PC$ is correct but can you please,correct the statement ?

Comment: From the explanation that $AYBC$ and $PYBX$ are cyclic, I assume the text of the problem was meant to state that $Y$ is the foot of the altitude from $A$ to $PQ$ (and not $XZ$). The figure, too, implies the same thing.

Comment: @Saeed I edit now

Comment: Since points $Z, Q$ are analogous to points $X, P$, proving that $QBYZ$ is cyclic can be done similarly to proving that $PYBX$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

$ \angle 1 = \angle 2$

$ \angle 2 = \angle 3$

$ \angle 3 =\angle 4$  because AYBC is also cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Below when I use arcs I am referring to the circle $\omega_1$. By $\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$ I mean the arc on $\omega_1$ that passes from $A$ through $Z$ to $B$.
$$\widehat{BZQ} = \frac{\overset{\huge\frown}{AZ}+\overset{\huge\frown}{ZB}}{2} = \frac{\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}}{2} \qquad(1)$$
$$\widehat{BYQ} = 180^o - \widehat{BYP}$$
And as you proved, $PYBX$ is cyclic. Therefore:
$$\widehat{BXP} = 180^o - \widehat{BYP}$$
$$\therefore \widehat{BYQ} = \widehat{BXP} = \frac{\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}}{2} \qquad(2)$$
From (1) and (2) we have $\widehat{BZQ} = \widehat{BYQ}$ which means $QBYZ$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Since quadrilaterals $AZBX$ and $PYBC$ are cyclic, we have $$\angle QYB=\angle PXB=\angle AXB=\angle BZQ$$ which implies that quadrilateral $QBYZ$ is cyclic.